# IIS URL Rewrite Redirect Rule

Tags: iis-7

I have one website with dynamic syntax

url: test.company.com/ssp/...

I would like to redirect to https

http://test.company.com/ssp/test > https://test.company.com/ssp/test

So far i have build one URL Rewrite

```
Pattern: (.*)

Condition: {HTTPS} / ^OFF$ 

Action: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
```

i only can redirect to https://test.company.com/ssp
so my ssp/test string is missing
I already tried https://{HTTP_HOST}/ssp/{R:1}.
Can someone explain what i'm missing